# Offset bottom of bar graph in matplotlib based on column value but only for first value (beginning of bar)

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

I am creating a stacked bar graph that actually represents layers of sediment in a geologic core(bar). The cores vary in length from 1.5 meters to 5+ meters. I've figured out most of the plotting and stacking, except for the beginning. Each core was collected in the ocean and at different water depths. I need each 'bar' to start at the depth of the water for that 'bar'. And then all the intervals after that are measured from the new 'zero' which is technically the ocean floor. Oh and each interval is actually 10 cm. Here is some simple data that mimics mine.

| CoreID | Lith | color | mbsl | bottom | top |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Core 1 | FSand | yellow | 21.24 | 0.01 | 0.0 |
| Core 1 | VFSand | green | 21.24 | 0.11 | 0.1 |
| Core 1 | FSand | yellow | 21.24 | 0.21 | 0.2 |
| Core 1 | VFSand | green | 21.24 | 0.31 | 0.3 |
| Core 2 | FSand | yellow | 17.92 | 0.01 | 0.0 |
| Core 2 | VFSand | green | 17.92 | 0.11 | 0.1 |
| Core 2 | FSand | yellow | 17.92 | 0.21 | 0.2 |
| Core 2 | VFSand | green | 17.92 | 0.31 | 0.3 |

So when I first plotted it all, it looked correct. For now the gaps are real. This is the code and image:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(4, 6))
bottom = np.zeros(3)

for coreID, group in grouped:
    for index, row in group.iterrows():
        plt.bar(x=coreID, height=((row['BtmInt'] - row['TopInt'])+9), bottom=(row['BtmInt']), 
                color=(row['color']), edgecolor=(row['color']), label=row['Lith'])

plt.xlabel('Core ID')
plt.ylabel('Depth (cm)')
plt.title('Fence Diagram')
plt.xticks(df['CoreID'].unique())
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
```

[image]

So then I tried this:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5, 7))
bottom = np.zeros(3)

for coreID, group in grouped:
    for index, row in group.iterrows():
        plt.bar(x=coreID, height=((row['bottom'] - row['top'])+0.9), 
        bottom=(row['bottom']+ row['mbsl']), color=(row['color']), edgecolor=(row['color']), 
        label=row['Lith'])

plt.xlabel('Core ID')
plt.ylabel('Depth (mbsl)')
plt.title('Fence Diagram')
plt.xticks(df['CoreID'].unique())
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
```

[image]

It appears to offset the start correctly but it is distorting the height of the layers. The gaps in the data are real for right now so they should appear in both. The idea is same as this image:

[image]

I feel like it's something like a well placed parentheses or something that I am missing. Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is due to the addition of `+.9` which is causing the distortion, I changed it to `*10` since the unit is 10cms and the data output is symmetrical, please check with the below changes!

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO 

# CoreID    Lith    color   mbsl    bottom  top
# Core 1    FSand   yellow  21.24   0.01    0.0
# Core 1    VFSand  green   21.24   0.11    0.1
# Core 1    FSand   yellow  21.24   0.21    0.2
# Core 1    VFSand  green   21.24   0.31    0.3
# Core 2    FSand   yellow  17.92   0.01    0.0
# Core 2    VFSand  green   17.92   0.11    0.1
# Core 2    FSand   yellow  17.92   0.21    0.2
# Core 2    VFSand  green   17.92   0.31    0.3

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5, 7))
bottom = np.zeros(3)

dfs = pd.read_html("untitled1.html")
df = dfs[0]
df_grouped = df.groupby('CoreID')
df_grouped
for coreID, group in df_grouped:
    for index, row in group.iterrows():
        plt.bar(x=coreID, height=((row['bottom'] - row['top'])*10), 
        bottom=(row['mbsl'] + row['bottom']), color=(row['color']), edgecolor=(row['color']), 
        label=row['Lith'])

plt.xlabel('Core ID')
plt.ylabel('Depth (mbsl)')
plt.title('Fence Diagram')
plt.xticks(df['CoreID'].unique())
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
```